# This rust solution to interpolation to a here document seems rough: Please can anyone suggest something better?

Tags: rust, heredoc

```
use std::borrow::Cow;
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn interpolate_hash_values<'life>(my_heredoc: &'life str, my_values: HashMap<&'life str, &'life str>) -> Cow<'life, str> {
    let mut tmp = Cow::from(my_heredoc);

    for (key, value) in my_values {
        let lid = format!("#{{{}}}", key);
        tmp = tmp.replace(&lid, &value).into();
    }
    tmp
}

fn main() {
    let myvalues: HashMap<&str, &str> = HashMap::from([
        ("ThisThing", "Now is the time for all good beings to come to fix up rust to be much better."),
        ("ThatThing", "Or else."),
        ("TheOtherThing", "What???????????????????????????????????????????????"),
    ]);
    let mut myheredoc = String::from(r#"
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Simle Here Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h3>Simle Here Document</h3>
    <p>
    Now is the time for all good denizens to play a companionable part.
    <p></p>
    #{ThisThing}
    <p></p>
    #{ThatThing}
    <p></p>
    #{TheOtherThing}
    </p>
    </body>
    </html>
    "#);
    println!("Here's the here doc before interpolations:  {}", myheredoc);
    let myresultstring = interpolate_hash_values(&mut myheredoc,myvalues);
    println!("Here's the here doc after interpolations:  {}", myresultstring);
}
```

This is to try to accomplish the interpolation to a here document function one might engage in Ruby, or most other such scripting languages.  The solution works, but is complicated enough, I fear there must be a better way; perhaps one that makes the above code look foolish.

Comment: Why the `Cow`? [It is not necessary](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e0246c96e17a55e2ec1c82e636393f1b) and it doesn't even help performance!

Comment: Define "better". In objective terms.

Comment: You know you can just do `.replace(...).replace(...).replace(...)`, right?

Comment: Instead of smashing around here with replace over and over, why not split your incoming stream into tokens using a parser, then evaluate each token and combine the results into a singular output string? There's a lot of parser options, including gems like [`nom`](https://docs.rs/nom/latest/nom/). Where templates are used frequently, you can even make a Rust procedural macro that bashes them into code, so they run really quick.

Comment: There's also many many string templating libraries that you can use for this kind of thing if you aren't bound to that specific syntax, like [tinytemplate](https://crates.io/crates/tinytemplate) or [handlebars](https://crates.io/crates/handlebars) just to name a couple.

Comment: Or simply with [`regex::Regex::replace_all`](https://docs.rs/regex/latest/regex/struct.Regex.html#method.replace_all): `Regex::new ("#{([^}]*)}").replace_all (my_heredoc, |c| my_values[c[1].as_str()])`

Comment: The tiniest library you could pull in for this is [`strfmt`](https://docs.rs/strfmt/latest/strfmt/). It has no dependencies.

Comment: The duplicate I linked isn't an exact duplicate of the question, but I think it's close enough to be useful.

Comment: Thank you guys.  I'll study all these before I lavish any more questions.  I hope the post was in bounds.  Rust is nice, but it's certainly not Ruby and not C.

Comment: To answer Chayim:  I know the focus on rust is system level productivity.  However, being able to do some of the same things I do easily in Ruby, I am guessing, is a good thing, and a general here document interpolation activity makes some things very clear and auditable.  Yes there are other ways to do it, but sometimes, I find this is very helpful.